# Movement in pygame when there shouldn't be

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a Brickbreaker game in Python 3.4 using pygame.

I have written code to make the paddle move left and right when you hit A or left, and D or right. But When you move the mouse or hit a key that shouldn't move the Paddle it moves anyway. I am new at python and I have no idea what is causing the code or how to fix it and my classmates can't figure it out either.

What's causing the problem and how do I fix it? Thanks!

```
import sys, pygame, brick, ball, paddle, os
from pygame.locals import *

class BrickBreaker:

# Constructor of the basic game class.
# This constructor calls initialize and main_loop method.
    def __init__(self):
        self.initialize()
        self.main_loop()

# Initialization method. Allows the game to initialize different parameters and load assets before the game runs

    def initialize(self):
        pygame.init()
        pygame.key.set_repeat(1, 1)   #This means when I hold A or D it repeats it for you so it doesn't move only a little
        os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'
        self.width = 1280
        self.height = 720
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height))

        self.caption = "Brick Breaker!"             #This makes the top window say "Brick Breaker"
        pygame.display.set_caption(self.caption)

        self.framerate = 60


        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Sprites

        self.background_color = (255, 255, 255)
        self.ball = ball.ball()
        self.brick_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.paddle = paddle.paddle()

        self.create_bricks()

        self.sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.sprites.add(self.ball,self.brick_list,self.paddle)

#The location of the sprites

        self.paddle.rect.x = 520
        self.paddle.rect.y = 650
        self.ball.rect.x = 610
        self.ball.rect.y = 595

    def create_bricks(self):
        offsetx = 90
        offsety = 20

        y = 37
        for i in range(5):
            x = 138
            for j in range(8):
                b = brick.brick()
                b.rect.x = x*j + offsetx
                b.rect.y = y*i + offsety
                self.brick_list.add(b)
                j+=1
            i+=1

# main loop method keeps the game running
# calls the update and draw methods to keep the game alive.
    def main_loop(self):
        while True:
            gametime = self.clock.get_time()
            self.update(gametime)
            self.draw(gametime)
            self.clock.tick(self.framerate)


# Update method contains game update logic, such as updating the game
# variables, checking for collisions, gathering input, and
# playing audio.
    def update(self, gametime):
        self.ball.rect.y -= 10
        events = pygame.event.get()

        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()

# This allows you top move the paddle left and right

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_a or event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    self.paddle.rect.x -= 15
                if event.key == pygame.K_d or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    self.paddle.rect.x += 15



# Stopping the paddle from going off screen
            self.paddle.rect.x = self.paddle.rect.x - 1
            if self.paddle.rect.x < 0:
                self.paddle.rect.x = 0

            self.paddle.rect.x = self.paddle.rect.x - 1
            if self.paddle.rect.x > 1065:
                self.paddle.rect.x = 1065


# Draw method, draws the current state of the game on the screen
    def draw(self, gametime):
        self.screen.fill(self.background_color)
        self.sprites.draw(self.screen)
        self.sprites.update()
        pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    game = BrickBreaker()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code is causing it to move the the paddle constantly to the left

```
 #Stopping the paddle from going off screen
        self.paddle.rect.x = self.paddle.rect.x - 1
        if self.paddle.rect.x < 0:
            self.paddle.rect.x = 0

        self.paddle.rect.x = self.paddle.rect.x - 1
        if self.paddle.rect.x > 1065:
            self.paddle.rect.x = 1065
```

try deleting the two assignment lines i.e. 'self.paddle.rect.x = self.paddle.rect.x - 1'